# How to inflate menu to a AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-menu

`AlertDialog` allows us to set custom views using `setView()` method. But what I wanted is to show menus as we use to show them in `toolbar`. Like inflating a `menu.xml` from the menu folder of android resource and make it to be appeared in an `AlertDialog`.

Comment: use **[PopupMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html)**

Comment: use `PopupWindow` for your purpose and  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40302997/8164071) might helpful

Comment: use popupMenu Example from here : https://www.javatpoint.com/android-popup-menu-example

Answer (score 0):

Create an activity and theme it as a Dialog. In this activity use the general Menu code.Now use this Activity as a Dialog window where you want a Dialog.